# Two elementary number theory generalities about sums of squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need help with the following two generalities:

What is the characterization of primes that are sums of two squares?

And what is the characterization of $n\ge 1$ that are sums of two squares?

I'm hoping I'm over thinking these two generalities, but they seem extremely broad to me.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is sometimes called [Fermat's Christmas theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares).  The primes are $2$ and all those of the form $4k+1$.  For composites, all prime factors of the form $4k+3$ must occur an even number of times.